# Java and cmake: package does not exist

Tags: java, cmake

I am installing [this tool](https://github.com/srndic/hidost) (using cmake) which calls the following:

```
import tv.porst.swfretools.dissector.console.ConsoleDumper;

public class SWFExtractor {

    /**
    * @param args - command-line arguments; this program 
    *               requires the path to the SWF file to 
    *               be analyzed as its first argument
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConsoleDumper.dump(args[0]);
    System.out.println("OKAY - DONE!");
    }

}
```

However, it returns an error saying package does not exist:

[image: Screen capture of the error.]

Here is the content of the JAR file in question:

[image: JAR file contents.]

And here is the CLASSPATH:

> user@ubuntu:~$ echo $CLASSPATH
>   :/home/user/swfretools_140/dissector.jar:/home/user/swfretools_140:/usr/local/include/dissector.jar

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you follow [this](https://github.com/srndic/hidost/blob/master/INSTALL.rst)?

Comment: Yes I did, installed the specified versions exactly, otherwise, it wouldn't work, as there are multiple checks throughout the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it cannot see the classpath. You can try to modify the file `hidost/CMakeLists.txt` by changing the line:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SWFExtractor.class
COMMAND javac -d ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SWFExtractor.java)
```

to

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SWFExtractor.class
COMMAND javac -d ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} -cp $ENV{CLASSPATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SWFExtractor.java)
```

EDIT:
I have a typo, change it to  `-d ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} -cp $ENV{CLASSPATH}`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the new line and got an invalid flag error:


javac: invalid flag: /home/ahmed/hidost-master/hidost
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
make[2]: *** [../hidost/SWFExtractor.class] Error 2
make[1]: *** [hidost/CMakeFiles/SWFExtractor.class.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Tried that and got the following error:
'javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
make[2]: *** [../hidost/SWFExtractor.class] Error 2
make[1]: *** [hidost/CMakeFiles/SWFExtractor.class.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2'
Tried switching -d and -cp and their arguments, and didn't work either.

Comment: it seems strange. Can you try again with `COMMAND javac -cp $ENV{CLASSPATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SWFExtractor.java)`

Comment: Apologies for the late response. I tried the new command and got the same error. Thank you for helping me with this error, really appreciate it. I am falling behind schedule and looks like I will be dropping the tool from the experiment. Thanks again!